# Mysterious white space on the right of my left when I scroll to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making my portfolio website and since a few days I'm struggling with a problem I have... I searched everywhere on the internet, there were similar problems but I could not solve them (well yes, but it brings me another problem).

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qafCD.png)
(I specify that the problem is not the size of my navbar, when I remove it I have the same problem)

[not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRSYO.png)

I have a mysterious white space when I scroll to the right and the window is not full screen... I tried all the margin and padding possible and the only solution I found is :

```
*{
 overflow-x :hidden
}
```

except that it does it on the whole page and then on other elements it cuts them off when they go out of their frame when I don't want to... and so I tried to put the overflow-x hidden individually on all the elements of my page but there is nothing that changes... it only works by putting * ...

I specify that I code with react so the * cuts all the elements of each component and that's not what I want... I put my code below

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import profil from "../../media/5847f5bdcef1014c0b5e489c.png"
import Aos from 'aos';
import "./BlocPresentation.css"
import { FaTwitterSquare } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { FaGithubSquare } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { FaLinkedin } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { RiMailFill } from 'react-icons/ri';
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

const BlocPresentation = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        Aos.init()
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className="presentation" id='accueil'>

            <div className="bloc-photo-presentation"><img className="img-presentation" src={profil} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="pos-texte-presentation">
                <div className="bloctexte">
                    <p className="Bonjour texte">Hello World,</p>
                    <p className="Prenom texte">Je suis Diego</p>
                    <p className="etudiant texte">Étudiant en développement Web</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div className="div4">
                <a href=''><i className="mail"><FaGithubSquare size={22} /></i></a>
                <a href=''><i className="mail"><FaLinkedin size={22} /></i></a>
                <a href=''><i className="mail"><FaTwitterSquare size={22} /></i></a>
                <a href=''><i className="mail"><RiMailFill size={24.5} /></i></a>


            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default BlocPresentation;
```

CSS :

```
.presentation {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    background-color: #1F1D2C;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;



}

.image {
    height: 100vh;
}

i {
    color: white;
}

.bloc-photo-presentation {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 6 / 9;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.pos-texte-presentation {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 6;
}

.div4 {
    grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 6;
}


.jesuis {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
}

.img-presentation {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 55%;
    width: 45%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px black;

}


.div4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 8vw;
}

.texte {
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.textebloc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}


.pos-texte-presentation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Bonjour {
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.etudiant {
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.Prenom {
    font-size: 3vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width:450px) {

    .presentation {
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .background-presentation {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 12 / 8;
        ;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: #1F1D2C;

    }

    .image {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    i {
        color: white;
    }

    .bloc-photo-presentation {
        grid-area: 2 / 3 / 7 / 6;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;

    }

    .pos-texte-presentation {
        grid-area: 7 / 2 / 10 / 7;

    }

    .bloctexte {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;

    }

    .div4 {
        grid-area: 10 / 4 / 11 / 8;
    }

    .img-presentation {
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 55%;
        width: 140%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px black;


    }

    .texte {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    .Bonjour {
        font-size: 10vw;
    }

    .etudiant {
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

    .Prenom {
        font-size: 6vw;
    }

}
```

( yes there must be things not very clean, I am a beginner ;) )

Comment: Do you test `*{box-sizing: border-box}` ?

Comment: There is already box-sizing: border-box; but nothing always the same problem :/

Comment: could you give me link of your website or add snippet code to your question?

Comment: I found the solution, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the devtools there is a little arrow inside a box. It's the second button to the left of "Elements". `ctrl + shift + c` should hotkey you into it.

With that little selector tool, you can hover around your webpage, hover over that dangling mysterious whitespace and click.

You'll now see the element which is causing your problems. Have a scroll through the CSS and fearlessly change stuff until the whitespace disappears. Good luck!

Comment: This is probably on of the best answers ever. "fearlessly change stuff until the whitespace disappears" There may be a better way, but we've all done this, and it always works!

Comment: unfortunately, I added a picture in my question. When I select this tool (which I knew) I can't select the element... and I've already tried to remove everything one by one but as soon as there are more than 3 lines I have this blank space and below I have 3 components of the same size and I don't have this problem

Comment: On your first screenshot there was a bluey box in the top right that looked like it may have been causing the problem. But your second screenshot seems to have made that disappear. Can you scroll down to see if there's anything selectable causing the overlay?

Comment: Yes, I purposely reduced the navigation bar to width:80% to show that this is not the problem, because even when I remove the navigation bar in App.js, I have the same problem. And I have this problem on two pages out of 6. I don't understand :/

Comment: Well done for finding the solution yourself. I did happen to find a good little tip from Kevin Powell today on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ii-lSK2_Nu4 

He suggests adding * { background: rgba(0,255,0,0.2) } to your css, this can help see all the overlapping elements visually. I'll definitely be trying that next time I run into a similar problem, and I hope it can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution! It was the "fade-left" of AOS library... it made me a margin and in fact I had no margin when the elements appeared. So I only had to do `.parents { overflow-x: hidden}` on the parent elements of the elements with the fade-left effect! And like that no more problems !